# High latency spikes BCM4352

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, network-manager, 15.10

Here's the facts:
Using Ubuntu 15.10
Using network-manager (also tested with wpa_supplicant)
Using bcmwl_kernel_source (unable to compile broadcom_sta, other kernel_source versions are not working)
Connected to wpa/wpa2 wifi on wlan0
Lenovo Y50-70
Broadcom BCM4352

When not using internet, and pinging my router: a lot of 2-3ms pings and some at 50ms
When using internet (say youtube, a game or browsing): a lot of 3-4ms pings and every 1-2 minutes, something like 10x 5000ms pings with lost packets.

The problem is not my connection, nor my router. There is no lag spikes on  the other of my computers(including a ubuntu server on different hardware), and there was no lag spikes under windows 2 months ago.

I had problems installing bcmwl_kernel_source at first but it installed properly after.

I did remove the power management from wlan0

SO, where are these lag spikes coming from?
If someone has a clue, please help me :)

This is what happens, and for some reasons it sometimes don't do it at all, and at other times it is doing it every 2 minutes... [http://imgur.com/3x1Augo](https://imgur.com/3x1Augo)

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I don't have much to add at this time, but if you need another person to try things independently, feel free to hit me up.

Comment: Still no answer found... I tried for months to get this to work properly(changing network equipment in my home, changing drivers,cleaning up the computer) but nothing has worked yet :(